# Using RegExpressions with Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is a rule I am using in htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

(I want the Rule to allow "user" values of letters and/or numbers and nothing else)

Beginning of profile.php:

$userid = filter($_GET['user']);  //this escapes and sanitizes the string

echo $userid; //want to see if the RegExp is allowing variable "user" to come thru

Test the following:
http://www.mysite.com/johnconnor

profile.php does not echo anything for $userid

Now test the following:
http://www.mysite.com/Johnconnor

profile.php DOES echo $userid as "Johnconnor"

Why is the RegExp not allowing the all lowercase "johnconnor" to get thru???
I've tried this without the "NC" as well and no luck.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly is not possible? to allow an all lowercase string is not possible?

Comment: it's not possible that having that rule you get capitalized url worked, and lowercased url - not.

Comment: well since this is not made up, what might be happening to cause this? I have copied and pasted the code I am using exactly as it appears.

Comment: try another browser. The only thing I can think of is browser cache. PS: show `var_dump($_GET);` output for both urls (without any modifications, just as is) PPS: I bet your `filter()` function makes no sense and does something weird

Comment: figured it out, thanks for your help though zerkms

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had a file in the main directory named johnconnor.sql that was messing things up.